I want to know where the specific implementation of the function is located?
using SearchMethod = std::function<int (std::size_t, double, pcl::Indices &, std::vector<float> &)>;
using SearchMethodSurface = std::function<int (const PointCloudIn &cloud, std::size_t index, double, pcl::Indices &, std::vector<float> &)>;

These two functions are in the 'feature.h' file, but I haven't found their specific implementations.
I want to understand the specific implementation code of the function.

Those are not functions. They are type aliases, for particular specialisations of std::function.
SearchMethodSurface is used to define a data member of pcl::Feature, which is initialised in pcl::Feature::initCompute() to either a radius search or a nearest K search, depending on other data members of the class.

I understand what you're saying, and I know that type achieves nearest neighbor search, but I still don't know the specific code implementation.

@ZhengMa there isn't one. You are meant to provide them, specific to your situation.

inline int
searchForNeighbors (std::size_t index, double parameter,
pcl::Indices &indices, std::vector &distances) const
{
return (search_method_surface_ (*input_, index, parameter, indices, distances));
}，Here is instantiated, but I still don't know the specific implementation process.

@ZhengMa search_method_surface_ is a different name to SearchMethodSurface, although it sounds like an instance of that type. Are searchForNeighbors and search_method_surface_ members of some class? Look at the constructor of that class.

@ZhengMa Is there only one constructor? Does anywhere else in that class assign to search_method_surface_?

’searchForNeighbors‘ is members of class,'search_method_surface_' is instance of that type.I haven't found the specific implementation code in the feature.hpp file.

search_method_surface_ is an object, not a function. There are two places it is assigned to, in initCompute, which are two different search algorithms selected based on the other data members of the class.
